# Is it correct $\nabla\cdot\nabla(G)=\nabla^2(G)$

Tags: calculus

For two scalar fields U and G:
$\nabla\cdot (U\nabla(G))=U\nabla\cdot\nabla(G)+(\nabla(U))\cdot(\nabla(G))$

Is it corect to proceed
$\nabla\cdot\nabla(G)=\nabla^2(G)$ ?

Comment: Yes. This is because \begin{align} \nabla \cdot \nabla &= (\partial_{x_{1}}, \partial_{x_{2}}, \partial_{x_{3}}, \dots, \partial_{x_{n}}) \cdot (\partial_{x_{1}}, \partial_{x_{2}}, \partial_{x_{3}}, \dots, \partial_{x_{n}}) \\
&= \partial^{2}_{x_{1}} + \partial^{2}_{x_{2}} + \partial^{2}_{x_{3}} + \dots + \partial^{2}_{x_{n}} \\ :&= \nabla^{2}\end{align}

Comment: Thanks alot !                                                        ...................

Comment: @Mattos you should have posted this as an answer.